# Публикация приложений

Tags: windows, установка, обновление, visual-studio

Скажите, вот я долго мучил VS, но так и не понял, как сделать так, чтобы прога просто проверяла по `http://site.ru/www/program.exe`, что если прога версии 1.0.0.0, значит не скачать обновление, если 1.0.0.1, то скачать обновление перед запуском программы (скачивание обновления происходит в папку, где лежит старый exe'ник). Без всяких setup'ov, просто скачивается обновленный файл .exe. Ух, думаю, вы поняли, что я имел ввиду. )

Answer (score 1):

Положите рядом с исполняемым файлом на сайте, скажем, текстовый файл, в который запишете версию. При запуске приложения, скачиваете этот файл, проверяете, что там записано, и если оно "то, что нужно", скачиваете новый исполняемый файлик по ссылке, если тоже, что и в текущем файле, то программа переходит в распоряжение пользователя без скачивания нового exe.

Но, насколько я себе это представляю, Ваше конечное приложение будет запускаться из другого, которое будет являться загрузчиком новой версии. т.е. сначала запускается загрузчик, проверяет то, что на сайте, если там новое, то скачивает, заменяет и запускает, если старое, запускает имеющийся exe.

Comment: вы наверно не поняли, мне это не надо писать, в VS уже есть такая функция, просто их там много(для публикации), и в них путаюсь... НЕ могу разобраться.

Comment: хм. понятно. тогда, увы, с выбором помочь не могу, т.к. в VS работал давно и совсем немного.
да и всеже странно это. в смысле, как прочесть инфо о файле, лежащем на сервере, не скачивая его... может я чего-то не знаю, но, мне кажется, это невозможно.

Comment: Да вот именно. Но т.к там много настроек я запутался.

Comment: Обычно системы обновления работают так, как указал @Johnny_Stray. Отдельно лежат файлы программы, отдельно база обновлений. Программа на клиенте просматривает базу и, если вышла новая версия, скачивает ее и устанавливает. Как можно иначе, я не представляю.